# How to setup SVG's viewbox, width and height which is scalable and responsive

Tags: html, css, svg

I am new to SVG design. 
Struggling to scale, zoom in/out with container and make it responsive to all the devices.

Is it even possible to design SVG in a way that fits in all the devices and handles browsing zoom in/out functionality?

I have tried to play with viewport and viewbox for each breakpoint.

e.g. for Desktop, I have SVG to fit in a container. should scale and zoom in and out with the container(svgClass).

```
.svgClass {
 background-image: url('assets/svg/desktop-svg.svg');
 width: "100%";
 height: 800px;
 position: absolute;
}

<div class="svgClass"></div>
```

Sample SVG

---desktop-svg.svg---

```
<svg width="1400" height="800" viewbox="0 0 1121 641">
-----
</svg>
```

It fits well with 100% browser zoom, but if in case of zoom in and zoom out SVG gets displaced.

To handle zoom in, I have increased viewport height="1400" and width="800" compared to viewbox (0 0 1121 641). which worked fine but zoom out still fails.

Had tried out: Removed width and height from viewport, also tried with setting auto and 100% with width and height. No success.

How to design SVG which can scale with the container and stay responsive, second do we need to setup viewport and viewbox for each device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to explain with an example in which svg is in the parent container.
The parent container in the application will look like a gray square
Svg will not have the width and height in the header of the svg file but the `viewBox` must be mandatory to ensure adaptability

I used `input` to show how with changing the width of the parent container the dimensions of the SVG are proportionally changed

```css
.container {
width: var(--w1,60px); 
background:#EAEAEA;
 
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="range" 
           min="60" 
           max="600" 
           oninput="document.querySelector('.container').style.setProperty('--w1', this.value + 'px');" 
           value="0">
    <span>width Container</span><br> 
</div>
<div class="container" >
    <svg  viewBox="0 0 120 120">     
        <defs>
            <mask id="msk1">
                <circle class="maskCircle" cx="60" cy="60" r="40" fill="none" 
                        stroke="white" stroke-width="8" 
                        stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="251.2">
                    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="3s" 
                             values="251.2;0" fill="freeze" 
                             repeatCount="indefinite" />
                </circle>
            </mask>
        </defs>
        <circle class="background" cx="60" cy="60" r="40" fill="none" 
                stroke="#E4E4E4" stroke-width="8" />
        <circle class="default" cx="60" cy="60" r="40" fill="none" 
                stroke="black" 
                stroke-width="8"
  stroke-dasharray="3.14" 
                stroke-dashoffset="40"  
                mask="url(#msk1)">
  
        </circle>
    </svg>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<div>
<input type="range" min="60" max="600" oninput="document.querySelector('.container').style.setProperty('--w1', this.value + 'px');" value="0"><span>width Container</span><br> 
</div>
```

These lines need to be removed from the application since the `input` in this example serves only to demonstrate the adaptability of SVG when resizing the parent container

*Practical advice:*

1. When developing an adaptive SVG application, assign for example `viewBox ="0 0 200 200"`with dimensions equal to the smallest size of the gadget's screen and when drawing in a vector editor, do not go beyond the boundaries of the document - 200x200px
2. When you do not assign the width and height of the svg application becomes adaptive that is, it will occupy the entire screen of the gadget

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >
```

At screen resolution, let's say 1400px svg will increase by 7 times

3. If, for example, you want the SVG to occupy only one quarter of the parent container, you must specify 25% percent width and height

```
<div class="container" style="width:25%; height:25%;"> 
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 200" >
    .... 
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that be responsive to all the standard breakpoints or we need to update viewport or viewbox ?

Comment: @mayank No need to update, this will work with any width of the parent container

Comment: Initially or onload it fits well but while zoom in SVG shrink faster than relative elements like footer or header. Can this be handled ?

Comment: @mayank I would be happy to help, but here the layout of your project is already having an impact. Here you need to look for solutions yourself

Answer (score 1):

Remove your "width" and "height" attributes, and just work with the viewBox numbers. Now your SVG will auto-fit inside whatever you're using as its container (a DIV?), otherwise your width and height are fighting with the DIV's width and height.